# iPhone application rejection in APP Store due to Private API

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I have submitted an app to appstore but unfortunately it got rejected due to following reasons:

- **We found that your app uses one or more non-public APIs, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines. The use of non-public APIs is not permissible because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change. 
  We found the following non-public API/s in your app:
  The app failed private API: setContentToHTMLString**

The API which we have used in our project was a private API so please suggest me an alternative solution for the same.

Comment: Are you looking for an alternative to the API or a way to circumvent Apple's policies? The later is illegal. The former would require you sharing the API used; or, at least, telling the community what this API does.

Comment: Not illegal, but not permitted by Apple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setContentToHTMLString` is a private API method for `UITextView`..

You should use a `web view` which has a method `loadHTML` .. this will solve the problem (since it is documented)